# How to: linq query

Tags: linq

I am trying to get a record from database using linq but it keep return no record

it is very basic sql statment
select * where productid ='12553'

however the following code does not return any result. Please advise. thx you

```
private static IEnumerable<ProductModel> GetAllProduct(string productId)
        {
            using (var dc = new TestEntities())
            {
                var result = (from a in dc.Products
                              where a.productid == productId
                              select new ProductModel
                              {
                                  ProductId = a.productid,
                                  Name = a.ProductName


                              });
                return result.Distinct().ToList();
            }


        }
```

Comment: Your Linq is correct. It must be your data that is not what you expect

Answer (score 2):

You don't need projection here:

```
using (var dc = new TestEntities())
{
    var result = from a in dc.Products
                 where a.productid == productId
                 select a;
    return result.Distinct().ToList();
}
```